# Dragon Quest Heroes (2015): Status effect and mitigation

Tags: dragon-quest-heroes

Some enemies have attacks that cause:

1. move interruption
2. knocking you into the air
3. being in a daze on ground

There are items that mitigate them but I'm not sure which item plays what role.

What does Blast Resistance do? does it counteract any of the above? What are the items that correspond to prevention of these statuses?